# How to add conditional styleclass to React AsyncTypeahead

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

i need to add the custom CSS class based on the condition like "direction rtl and ltr" to the React AsyncTypeahead can anyone suggest me how to add that 
can we add class name as below or how to use it.

```
<AsyncTypeahead
       className=""
       id="typeahead"
       delay={800}
       emptyLabel="please select"
       ignoreDiacritics={true}
       minLength={3}
       onSearch={this.onSearch}
       placeholder="Insert text to search"
       promptText="Searching"
       searchText="Searching"
       renderMenuItemChildren={(selectedItem: State, props) => {

       }}
     />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional operating

`className={direction ? styleOne : styleTwo }`

Comment: AsyncTypeahead tag does not have the attribute  "className" @Han